# SQLite3 select statement simplified?

Tags: database, select, sqlite

I have multiple tables in my database, all of which have two similar columns: `Year` and `AcceptanceRate`

I want to concatenate all the `AcceptanceRate` values from all the tables for the year 2009.

I tried something like that:

```
Select AcceptanceRate from Table1, Table2, Table3 where Year=2009
```

But that obviously won't work, since it will return that the AcceptanceRate is ambiguous as to which table I am referring to.

I'm wondering if there is an easy way to do this that doesn't require me merging all the tables together (I have a total of 20 tables) first and then extracting the `AcceptanceRate` from that table?

I know this works:

```
Select AcceptanceRate from Table1 where Year=2009 
UNION 
Select AcceptanceRate from Table2 where Year=2009 
UNION 
Select AcceptanceRate from Table3 where Year=2009
```

I'm just curious if there is a much simpler way to do this?

Comment: In what way do these tables differ in their column structure? (If they don’t, then you should perhaps not have 20 tables in the first place, but just one.)

Comment: @CBroe the tables are large. They each represent different stats in different years for a different Conference. It's just a lot more organized if I had them all in separate tables.

Comment: Perhaps creating a VIEW out of your union-ized selects would help deal with this a little more comfortably …

Comment: You wouldn't have this problem if your database were properly normalized. Anyway, with this schema, your query is the simplest way (but UNION ALL is faster than UNION).